# OpenCV using command line argument for input image (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to load an image from a file specified on the command line then process it using the OpenCV command HoughCircles. What happens is that I am opening the file:

```
img = cv2.imread(argv[0],0)
```

Then trying to use the following function:

```
def _getCircles(img):
  _circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=1,maxRadius=20)
```

But returns the error:

```
cv2.error: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

However if I load the file directly ie change argv[0] to the explicit filename everything works perfectly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python and most other languages `argv[0]` contains the program name. Try using `argv[1]` to get the correct result.

Here is some [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) to help you. Python has an amazing library of documentation I highly recommend using it.

Comment: this is my fault for not explaining it right. I know about argv i was passing arguments from __main to def main(argv) via (sys.argv[1:]). Problem was silly using -t instead of -i for command line input. Technically your answer for the question I posed is correct but its my fault for not asking things properly

Comment: @MattStokes Shame I wasn't of use but I'm glad you found and fixed the problem anyway.